# SAP-1 (Simple as Possible) W Bus

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, computer-architecture

I'm currently investigating the SAP-1 to build in order to grasp a really good understanding of simple 8 bit computers.

There are a few questions that I would like clearing up.

What exactly is the WBUS? Looking at the logical diagram attached below I'm struggling to understand what the WBUS is, I'm presuming it may possibly be the inputs to the computer but cannot be certain.

Am I right in assuming all a register is is a place to store a value and each value the shift register is storing is put into context by the clock cycle?

[image]

Comment: The first page of the designer's blog (http://rmacalagay012690.blogspot.ca/) says " W bus - A single 8 bit bus for address and data transfer."  I looked at this thing previously, and I recall thinking that he had simplified computer design to the point of confusion.  I suggest you study a real 8 bit micro, like the Atmel ATMega.  You'll see how real microcontrollers work, without the confusing simplifications of the SAP-1.

Comment: You might like to read  thelinuxmaniac.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cad-sapreport.pdf‎

Comment: But what exactly is the BUS? Is it just wires or a chip or?

Comment: The bus is 8 "wires".  Each "wire" (really, a network of wires) is connected to every component.  (If you did this as multiple boards, each board would have a trace for each bus line, and there would be connectors between the boards.  The PC, IR, ALU and A reg all have `E` (for "Enable") inputs.  When you assert `E` on component X that activates a  tri-state inverter to drive each bus wire from X.  Your control needs to make sure only one component's `E` is asserted on any particular cycle.

Comment: So think of a bus as a _multiplexor_ that is spread out all over your design.  Each set of tri-states that can drive the bus is sometimes called a "multiplexor _arm_" (I guess in analogy to an octopus having multiple arms.)

Comment: Thanks! Great answer, so to summarise, the Data Bus isn't an actual IC, just wires that connect each part of the computer together into oneanother?

Comment: Right.  In this design the tristates (multiplexor arms) are hidden inside the PC/RAM/IR/ALU/A-reg, and the part labeled "WBus" is just wires.

Comment: Thankyou. Can you recommend further reading to increase my understanding on this?

Comment: You can see all in here by details - small steps 41 videos : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyznrdDSSGM&list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU